# How best to handle previously installed modules when upgrading Perl version with homebrew

Tags: perl, homebrew

I run into this every so often: I run a `brew install foobar` and as a result, Perl version gets updated. Whenever this happens, the Perl modules that I had installed are no longer found because they were installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/` and the new version is now looking in `/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.1_1/`.

I have/had a ton of modules installed with the previous version and I'd rather not reinstall all of them (at least manually). What's the best way to have the previously-installed modules work with the new Perl version?

For such a small version change above, I could presumably just copy all of the files from the `5.32.0` dir to the `5.32.1_1` dir, but preferably there is a more general and/or robust solution for when the version change is more substantial.

Comment: Perl maintains binary backwards compatibility between minor versions. So if the two `perl` were built with the same settings (e.g. threading), you can copy the files over. (In fact, when building 5.32.1_1, you could have told it to add 5.32.0's folder to the search list.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cpan` command can make an "autobundle" file. You'd use the `cpan` from the prior installation to do this:

```
$ cpan -a
Creating autobundle in /Users/brian/.cpan/Bundle
Reading '/Users/brian/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 19 Mar 2021 05:41:03 GMT

Package namespace         installed    latest  in CPAN file
Algorithm::C3                  0.11      0.11  HAARG/Algorithm-C3-0.11.tar.gz
Algorithm::Cron                0.10      0.10  PEVANS/Algorithm-Cron-0.10.tar.gz
Algorithm::Diff              1.1903     1.201  RJBS/Algorithm-Diff-1.201.tar.gz
...
version::regex               0.9924    0.9928  LEONT/version-0.9928.tar.gz
vmsish                         1.04      1.04  SHAY/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz
warnings                       1.47      1.47  SHAY/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz
warnings::register             1.04      1.04  SHAY/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz

Wrote bundle file
    /Users/brian/.cpan/Bundle/Snapshot_2021_03_20_00.pm
```

At the top of that file, there are instructions on installing it. Use the `cpan` from the new installation to handle this part:

```
package Bundle::Snapshot_2021_03_20_00;

$VERSION = '0.01';

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

Bundle::Snapshot_2021_03_20_00 - Snapshot of installation on otter on Sat Mar 20 00:19:35 2021

=head1 SYNOPSIS

perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::Snapshot_2021_03_20_00'
```

I hardly ever do this though. When I install a new perl and want to use a new project on it, I install the project. That project installs whatever it needs. I like the fresh start instead of carrying over stuff I might not be using anymore.

Also, note that `cpan` installs the latest versions of whatever you are asking for. If you need particular versions, `cpanm` is easier to handle. And, in that case, you might consider using a `cpanfile` to lock down exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is akin to what I was looking for. For posterity, noting that the autobundle needs to be run with the prior version of Perl - e.g., `/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'autobundle'`. Also, the installation of the bundle with the new version of Perl took a while, partly because it kept stopping for input. Looks like there are some cpan options to help with that, such as `o conf inactivity_timeout 1`, `o conf allow_installing_module_downgrades 0`, `o conf allow_installing_outdated_dists 0`, and/or env vars `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1`, `PERL_CANARY_STABILITY_NOPROMPT=1`.